# 'MissingComponentException' with 'CanvasGroup.interactable' in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Working with `Slider` and `Button` components in [Unity](https://unity.com) 2021.1.1f1.
Beside some other operations, I want to toggle the `interactable` property of it.

Calling it as an `CanvasGroup` component, because i want to use the same code for all.

Only the `interactable` property throws an `MissingComponentException`.

Here is my shortened code:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Minigame03Ingredient : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public int ReferenceValue;
    public int Increment;
    public int IncrementDelay;
    private int defaultIncrementDelay;
    public int feedbackValue = 0;
    private CanvasGroup button;
    internal Minigame03Main minigame;
    private bool flowActivated = false;
    private bool flowTriggered = false;
    private int leftIncrementDelay = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        this.defaultIncrementDelay = this.IncrementDelay;
        this.button = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        if (TryGetComponent(out Slider slider)) {
            slider.maxValue = this.defaultIncrementDelay;
            slider.value = this.defaultIncrementDelay;
        }
        this.button.interactable = false; // Nur zum Test
    }
...
}
```

And here is the console message from the Unity Editor:

```
MissingComponentException: There is no 'CanvasGroup' attached to the "waterSlider" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a CanvasGroup to the game object "waterSlider". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
Minigame03Ingredient.Start () (at Assets/_Scripts/Games/Minigame03/Minigame03Ingredient.cs:28)
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Well the error message seems quite self explanatory ... you are doing `this.button = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();` but there is no `CanvasGroup` component attached to the **same** GameObject as your `Minigame03Ingredient` component ...

Comment: @derHugo Okay, so `GetComponent<>()` does not throw an Exception itsself.
Only if i really try to access the component later?
Okay, good to know. Thank you :-)

Comment: Btw it is [`Selectable.interactable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html) ...

Comment: @derHugo Oh thank you very much! :-D 
To use `Selectable` was the solution. :-)
The Unity Documentation pointed me to `CanvasGroup`, when i searched for `interactable`: https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/CanvasGroup-interactable.html

Comment: Isn't the documentation link missing?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have not found the coresponding link in the 2021.1er documentation so i posted the only link that looks suitable but was the reason, why i made the mistake to use `CanvasGroup.interactable` instead of `Selectable.interactable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use an `Selectable` instead of an `CanvasGroup` here.

Answer (score 1):

When there isn't any component attached which is queried with GetComponent<ComponentType>() method, it returns a null value and doesn't throw any exception.

So, if you do the following:

```
this.button = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>(); // this.button will be assigned to null.

this.button.interactable = false; // Throws an exception because this.button is null.
```

This is something like null.some_property, which will throw a null reference exception or a missing reference exception.